# div auto scrolls on load to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, autoscroll

```
'''
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Refresh</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
    window.onload=function () {
        var objDiv = document.getElementById("load_chats");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    };
</script>
<style>
    #load_chats{
        width: 95%;
        margin: auto;
        height: 400px;
        overflow-y:auto;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-image: url("../a/images/paper_pic.jpg");
    }
    #chat_window{
        width: 95%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #right{
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid darkslateblue;
        width: 40%;
        min-height: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        float: right;
        display: inline;
        clear: both;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        background-color: white;
    }
    #left{
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid darkslateblue;
        width: 40%;
        min-height: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        clear: both;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        background-color: white;
    }
    #date{
        text-align: right;
    }
    p{}

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="chat_window">

 <div id="load_chats"></div>
</div>
<form name="add_chat" method="post">

        <label><textarea name="chat_content" id="chat_content"></textarea></label>
        <input type="button" name="chat_button" id="chat_button"  value="Chat"/>
</form>

</body>
 </html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chat_button').click(function(){
        var tweet_txt = $('#chat_content').val();
        //trim() is used to remover spaces
        if($.trim(tweet_txt) !== '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"insert.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{chat_content:tweet_txt},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#chat_content').val("");
                }
            });
        }
     });

    setInterval(function(){//setInterval() clearInterval()
        $('#load_chats').load("fetch.php").fadeIn("slow");

    }, 1000);
});
</script>
'''
```

so im using the part of my code

```
'''
 <script>
    window.onload=function () {
        var objDiv = document.getElementById("load_chats");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    };
</script>
...
```

on another page and it works just fine but when i move it over here to this page its not working
any help would be awesome. im making a chat that updates from an sql database and it just want it to start at the bottom of the text like you would see on your phone, ive been looking this up and nothing is working making me go back to window.onload=function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page just load the height of the div is `0`, sinse it's empty. so you scroll it to `0`. You have to scroll the div to bottom **AFTER** you load the `fetch.php` into it.

```
 $('#load_chats').load("fetch.php", {}, function(data){
        var objDiv = $("#load_chats")[0];
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
 }).fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Awsome, ty I'll try that later today

Comment: got around to trying it thank you very much worked perfect